# Laravel: View::share(...) with $response->assertViewHas(...) in phpunit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-blade

I share my params with view like this:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::share('params', $params);
view()->share('params', $params);
```

and testing it with `phpunit` like so

```
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get($url);
$response->assertViewHas('params');
```

And I'm getting this `FAILURE`

> Failed asserting that an array has the key 'params'.

When I share like so, phpunit is green

```
return view('account', compact('params'));
```

How can I test variables shared with `view()->share('params', $params);` ?

I'm using `Laravel 5.8`

Comment: Are you sharing the view data in the `boot` method of the AppServiceProvider

Comment: No. Why? Please explain.

Comment: Normally sharing data to all views is done in the AppServiceProvider. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I'm not sharing data with all views, I'm sharing it on demand. I've created a partial view and use it in many views. I don't want to copy-paste controller code that collects data for this partial view, so I created a class for it. Now when I know - view will have this partial, I'll execute according class in controller and it makes data structure and shares it to the view.

Comment: So I looked into this a bit more because it intrigued me. It seems like Laravel's `assertViewHas` helper doesn't check the data that is shared with the view, which is separate from data passed to the view explicitly.

Comment: Ok, how we can check data shared to the view? And what If I'd share data to the view from the view?